# Unable to install Python 3.5 within Windows XP Professional

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-xp, python-3.5

I am attempting to install Python 3 from within Windows XP Professional; however I receive the following screen (there is no install button):

[image: python install]

In my opinion this is obviously an unreported error, or a rendering problem. How is this problem alleviated? If this problem can be overcome, is it a sign of additional related issues?

Comment: Does running the installer as admin change the outcome?

Comment: @qwertyuip9 hang on i needed to set the `Administrator` password... although my user *should* have the same rights...

Comment: @qwertyuip9 same result. bummer

Comment: If you're not set on doing python 3.5, you could try python 3.4 or try ActivePython (which includes Python 3.4) which appears to work on Windows XP. Also, python 3.5.0rc4 came out today, maybe that might work?

Comment: Python 3.5 dropped support of Windows XP so I would rather call anything XP-related issue incompatibility than error and not expect to be fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What versions of Python will work in Windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516712/what-versions-of-python-will-work-in-windows-xp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

May be a bug in the installer? Try Python 3.4.3 - https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/python-3.4.3.msi

Or click on white space in the 3.5.0rc3 installer.

[image]

Comment: OK lemme download that into the VM

Comment: Oh my! I clicked in the white space of the window shown in my question. Apparently that is the `next` button. Why don't you add that to your question; seeing as how it is a bug?

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi yeah, it is really a bug. 3.4.3 installed correctly for me.

Comment: _clicked in the white space of the window shown in my question_


    very predictable behavior /sarcasm

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but it would be neat if you will append the answer with what the `next` button is (the white space). Some people (including me) don't always peruse the comments of a question.

Comment: "clicked the white space [...] sarcasm" I was really just wanting to get focus of the window so I could close it. How very odd, eh?

Answer (score 15):

Sadly, any version of Python past version 3.4.3 is no longer compatible with Windows XP. They stopped supporting it all together - see *[3.5 install fails poorly on Windows XP](https://bugs.python.org/issue25143)*.

Answer (score 4):

from  [python.readthedocs.io](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/windows.html) :

> As specified in PEP 11, a Python release only supports a Windows platform while Microsoft considers the platform under extended support. This means that Python 3.7 supports Windows Vista and newer. If you require Windows XP support then please install Python 3.4.

the last windows XP Python build is 3.4.4 :
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-344/
3.4.7 (2017-08-09) is available as code source

Answer (score 4):

While CPython 3.5 doesn't work on XP, there is [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/), an [alternative Python implementation](https://www.python.org/download/alternatives/) that does work.
However, current version PyPy3.5 v6.0 [doesn't yet support `asyncio` module](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2757/cant-import-asyncio-on-windows-importerror), probably the most interesting part of 3.5 update.

**2020 Update:** PyPy supports `asyncio` since [v7.1.1](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/release-v7.1.1.html), but I'm not sure whether it still supports XP. Leave a comment if you try it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Python download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), `Python 3.5+ cannot be used on Windows XP or earlier.`

Try using the latest supported version, [Python 3.4.10](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3410/).

Answer (score 1):

Just found this (Dec 2019)

Someone had built Python 3.4.10 for Windows XP. Since it comes from the third-party, use at your own risk,

[-->Download<--](http://matejhorvat.si/en/windows/python/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This guy has managed to run Python 3.5 on XP by placing a compatibility layer DLL (XomPie) between Python and Windows kernel and some tinkering:
https://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/2016/10/python-352-on-xp.html